# Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org

Tags: 13.10, gtk, gedit

When I try to gedit some files, then I received these from the terminal window. There is already one post about this: [Gtk-WARNING : Calling Inhibit failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376426/gtk-warning-calling-inhibit-failed)

But it is not solved. How can I solve it ? [image]

Comment: I'd very much like to know how to stop gtk warnings from all apps entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there so many console messages from GTK+ applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422254/why-are-there-so-many-console-messages-from-gtk-applications)

Answer (score 5):

To solve

```
IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/myPC/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

use `gksudo` or `gksu`instead of sudo to open the file,

```
gksudo gedit php.ini
```

or

```
gksu gedit php.ini
```

[More on gksudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

The next error

```
(gedit:12512): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

can be solved by updating `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0`

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

Comment: Lubuntu 14.04 comes with gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 but I still get the "Calling Inhibit failed" warning from Gedit 3.10.4.

Comment: same as comment above

Comment: "Calling inhibit failed" still happens on 14.04.3 LTS `apt-get dist-upgrade`d on January 2016. The suggested `apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0` is not necessary because the system would already be up to date.

Comment: Three comments above still valid under 16.04.2 LTS on July 30, 2017.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to not deal with such warnings. Use graphical frontend for sudo/su - gksu (in case of gnome) for running GUI programs as root. [Gtk-WARNING : Calling Inhibit failed](https://askubuntu.com/a/387238/60632)

Comment: The "calling inhibit failed" warning still happens if you use `gksudo gedit` which I understand is the same as `gksu gedit` on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

When starting an application from the command line, you can avoid verbose output in the terminal after starting the application by using the `NOHUP` flag before the command and an ampersand following the command.

For example, in this instance you would use:

```
nohup gedit &
```

or

```
nohup gedit
```

If you need `sudo` permission, you should use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo` to prevent other problems like so:

```
nohup sudo -i
```

[Click here for more info, possible dupe.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422254/why-are-there-so-many-console-messages-from-gtk-applications)