# Trying to get into Php and Apache2 and this came up

Tags: 14.04, networking, apache2, php

Okay so while I was installing Apache2 and php all of a sudden I got this

```
`**Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files**`
```

it happened while I tried to edit the index.html page

Thank you for the answers and happy holidays

Comment: if it came up while editing a file then it might be an error of the code editor. Btw which editor did you use

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/419783/gtk-warning-calling-inhibit-failed-gdbus-errororg